# Calling readFile twice on the same filehandle in node.js?

Tags: node.js, fs

If I have code like this

```
const fs = require('fs')

;(async () => {
  const fd = await fs.promises.open('test.txt')
  const a1 = await fd.readFile()
  const a2 = await fd.readFile()
  console.log({ a1, a2 }) //a2 is empty

  const fd2 = fs.openSync('test.txt')
  const b1 = fs.readFileSync(fd2)
  const b2 = fs.readFileSync(fd2)
  console.log({ b1, b2 }) //b2 is empty
})()
```

then the output is e.g.

```
{
  a1: <Buffer 68 74 74 70 73 3a 2f 2f 67 69 74 68 75 62 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 54 69 6d 55 6e 74 65 72 73 62 65 72 67 65 72 2f 6e 65 6f 67 69 74 0a 68 74 74 70 73 3a 2f 2f ... 38 more bytes>,
  a2: <Buffer >
}
{
  b1: <Buffer 68 74 74 70 73 3a 2f 2f 67 69 74 68 75 62 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 54 69 6d 55 6e 74 65 72 73 62 65 72 67 65 72 2f 6e 65 6f 67 69 74 0a 68 74 74 70 73 3a 2f 2f ... 38 more bytes>,
  b2: <Buffer >
}
```

Is there anyway to reset the filehandle position back to the start

Comment: For reasons I've never understood, there is no documented way to set the file position on an open file handle in nodejs.  Close the file and reopen it I guess or use `fs.read()` where you can specify the position to read from.  I think I once saw a third party native code module that could do it, but I can't seem to find it now.

Comment: I knew I'd looked into this before.  Here was that result: [How to move a filehandle's internal position without reading data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65571609/how-to-move-a-filehandles-internal-position-without-actually-reading-data).  The answer was, "you can't".